# Apache 2.2 subdomains are showing same site as of main domain

Tags: apache, subdomain, document-root

i have main site on www.domain.com and have created one subdomain called demo.domain.com
but when i try to access the subdomain  demo.domain.com, its showing the same site as my main domain, how do i fix this?
here are how i have defined the virtual hosts in my

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/demo.domain.com/public_html
     ServerName demo.domain.com
     ServerAlias www.demo.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

i even tried

```
service httpd restart
```

it throws

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Mon Jan 13 15:54:14 2014] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

i have added both the main domain and subdomain in the host file

```
[root@public_html]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
1.2.3.4 domain.com demo.domain.com
```

and i have created a A record for the subdomain name in my DNS manager pointing it to the my main vps IP - Address.
my DNS file

```
demo    IN A    1.2.3.4
@           IN A    1.2.3.4
www         IN A    1.2.3.4
```

so when i access domain.com and demo.domain.com it shows the same page as of domain.com

i have created a index.html in

**/var/www/demo.domain.com/public_html**

```
[root@public_html]# cat index.html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>www.example.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success: You Have Set Up a Virtual Host</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

so how i can fix this ? i am using centOS 6, 64 bit

**when i try to access the subdomain  demo.domain.com, its showing the same site as my main domain www.domain.com**

Comment: Do you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere in your httpd.conf? You will hit the default VirtualHost without this.

Comment: yes, i have #NameVirtualHost *:80
 in my httpd.conf but its commented out.

Comment: i just commented it out, and restarted apache and voila , it works .... +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As arco444  suggested.

try

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep NameVirtualHost
```

and comment out

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
```

so itll become

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

then restart apache by entering

```
service httpd restart
```

now it should show sub-domains their respective sites/pages.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it shows the same site as my main domain", does it show the subdomain as a subdirectory of the main domain? E.g., `www.domain.com/demo/`. That's fairly normal, though undesirable, behavior for some control panels and server setups. Instead of mucking with httpd.conf, you might get better results with /.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?domain\.com  [NC]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/demo  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^demo/?(.*)$  http://demo.domain.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Then what exactly is it showing when you type in demo.domain.com? What do you mean by "it shows the same site"? If the address bar shows demo.domain.com, what's wrong?